# Deploy 3rd party application war as spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have done some searches and cannot quite get the answer I am looking for. I have a 3rd party application packaged as a war with some external dependencies. I am looking to either convert to a spring boot application, or, be deployed in an embedded tomcat container in spring boot, would be interested in some approaches that some have taken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use spring boot here. Its more for the cases where you write the application by yourself and do not host already existing wars.

However, you can take a look at Embedded Tomcat capabilities. 
You can configure an embedded tomcat to pick the WAR from somewhere in a classpath so that it will load it.
Here is an [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809914/deploy-war-in-embedded-tomcat-7) (Doesn't worth to repeat an already answered question)

Another option is an embedded Jetty, which does basically the same but... with jetty.